# GridLayout index 0 to start at bottom left

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

The default `GridLayout` add elements starting from the top left to bottom right.

Whereby (0,0) is top left. How do I create a `GridLayout` such that the (0,0) is on bottom left alike to a real life graph coordinate?

I had a bit of a hard time using `getChildAt()` as the index starts at top left and ends at bottom right.

How do I change it such that it index starts at bottom left and ends at top right?

Comment: Have you heard about "RecyclerView With GridLayoutManager.."

Comment: Does your GridLayout have a fixed number of columns?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yes, it's a fixed 15(width)x20(height) layout. I did a short fix by doing some conversion to find the index.

Answer (score 0):

As my layout is fixed at 15 x 20. I wrote a method such that I can convert easily from a normal x-y coordinate to the index as such

```
 public static int convertToIndex(int x, int y){
            int graph_Y = 20 - y;
            int index = graph_Y * 15 + x - 1;
            return index;
        }
```